# Proving a set is open in the metric space $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

I have a little question here:

Prove that a set $(a,b)$ is open in $(\mathbb{R}, d)$.

I saw the solution and got stuck at one step only:

Take $x\in (a,b)$ , i.e. $a<x<b$,

Let $\epsilon= \min\{x-a, b-x\}$,

We have to prove that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset (a,b)$, so

Take $y\in B(x,\epsilon),$

$y\in B(x,\epsilon) \rightarrow y\in (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)\mathbf{\subset(x-(x-a), x+(b-x))} = (a,b)$.

I can't understand the statement in bold, why do we have the right to do that? Ok this is related to what we suppose $\epsilon$ to be at the top of the solution, but is this true if $m$ for example is the minimum of $n$ and $p$ then $(x-m,x+m) \subset (x-n, x+p)$??

Hope I illustrated well, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: We have $\epsilon\leq x-a$ hence $z-\epsilon\geq z-(x-a)$ for every $z$. Choosing $z=x$ leads to $x-\epsilon\geq x-(x-a)=a$. Likewise for the other side. If $m$ is minimum of $n$ and $p$ then $m\leq n$ so $x-m\geq x-n$ for every $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you say in your last paragraph is allowed, assuming $n$ and $p$ are positive. If we write it as inequalities, maybe it will be clearer:
$$
t\in (x-m, x+m) \iff x-m<t<x+m
$$
Note that we have $-n\leq -m$ and $m\leq p$, so we may expand that last inequality on the left and right to get
$$
x-n\leq x-m<t<x+m\leq x+p\\
\implies x-n<t<x+p
$$
which is the same as $t\in (x-n, x-p)$.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, if $m=\min{n,p}$, then $(x-m,x+m)\subset(x-n,x+p)$, because, if $y\in(x-m,x+m)$, then $y<x+m\leqslant x+p$ and $y>x-m\geqslant x-n$. Therefore, $y\in(x-n,x+p)$.